# Error: Failed executing DbCommand cannot execute insert command

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add an entity to one of my tables but an error occurred. You can find below model, controller and output debug:

noting that I'm using this approach in my entire project and there is no problem, i don't know why he called the `applicationUserId` it's not in the related model...

model:

```
    public class Rate
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ProjectId")]
        public Projects Project { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
   var rate = new Rate
    {
       ProjectId = CPVM.Id,
    };
   rateRepository.Add(rate);
```

Rep:

```
        public void Add(Rate entity)
        {
            db.Rate.Add(entity);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

debugger output:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Error: Failed executing DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (Size = 450), @p1='?' (DbType = Int32), CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
INSERT INTO [Rate] ([ApplicationUserId], [ProjectId])
VALUES (@p0, @p1);
```

DBContext

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Users");
            builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles");
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>().ToTable("UserClaims");
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().ToTable("UserRoles");
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>().ToTable("Userlogins");
            builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>().ToTable("RoleClaims");
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>().ToTable("UserTokens");

            builder.Entity<Bids>()
                       .HasKey(b => b.Id);
            builder.Entity<Languages>()
                .HasKey(l => l.Id);
            builder.Entity<Rate>()
                .HasKey(r => r.Id);
            builder.Entity<Projects>()
                .HasKey(p => p.Id);
            builder.Entity<TranslatorsLanguages>()
                 .HasKey(t => t.Id);


            builder.Entity<TranslatorsLanguages>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Languages)
                .WithMany(b => b.TranslatorsLanguagesList)
                .HasForeignKey(b => b.FromLanguage);

            builder.Entity<TranslatorsLanguages>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Languages)
                .WithMany(b => b.TranslatorsLanguagesList)
                .HasForeignKey(b => b.ToLanguage);

            builder.Entity<TranslatorsLanguages>()
                .HasOne(p => p.ApplicationUser)
                .WithMany(b => b.TranslatorLanguagesList)
                .HasForeignKey(b => b.TranslatorId);

            builder.Entity<Projects>()
                .HasOne(p => p.ApplicationUser)
                .WithMany(b => b.ProjectsList)
                .HasForeignKey(b => b.CustomerId);

            builder.Entity<Projects>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Languages)
                .WithMany(b => b.ProjectsList)
                .HasForeignKey(b => b.FromLanguage);

            builder.Entity<Projects>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Languages)
                .WithMany(b => b.ProjectsList)
                .HasForeignKey(b => b.ToLanguage);


            builder.Entity<Bids>()
                .HasOne(p => p.ApplicationUser)
                .WithMany(b => b.BidsList)
                .HasForeignKey(b => b.TranslatorId);

            builder.Entity<Bids>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Projects)
                .WithMany(b => b.BidsList)
                .HasForeignKey(b => b.ProjectId);
        }


        public DbSet<Languages> Languages { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Projects> Projects { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Rate> Rate { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TranslatorsLanguages> TranslatorsLanguages { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Bids> Bids { get; set; }


    }
```

Comment: Could you provide us the code of your DbContext class?

Comment: sure, i will attach it..

Comment: So you have an entity called ApplicationUser mapped to a table but not in the DbContext model. Define a DbSet for it.

Comment: No Sir, the DBSet Rate shouldn't be mapped to ApplicationUser. this is the point, i don't know why the compiler understood that I'm passing applicationUserId.

Comment: I didn't mean mapping ApplicationUser to the Rate model. Just add another field for ApplicationUser  : 
`public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers{ get; set; }`

Comment: I found that in the applicationUser model there is a reference for Rate model ```        public List<Rate> RateList { get; set; }
```
when i removed it, it works!!

Answer (score 0):

I found that in the applicationUser model there is a reference for Rate model `public List<Rate> RateList { get; set; }` when i removed it, it works!!